# Drop Type in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

There is another way to drop a type in oracle.

I know that FORCE can help me but it is not the best way.

If a want to drop a type with type or table dependents, how can I migrate all data
to new Type.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the question.  You start out talking about dropping a type.  You then say that using `FORCE` is "not the best way" but you don't tell us what metric you are using to determine "best" or what problem(s) `FORCE` creates or does not solve.  Then you end by talking about migrating one type definition to another.  What data are you talking about migrating?  Do you have tables defined on these types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can alter an existing type and migrate existing objects when you use keyword `CASCADE`, see documentation [ALTER TYPE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4002.htm#i2112577)

Comment: Thank you so much, just what I wanted!